# Force fetch from Cloud Firestore cache when offline

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently using Firebase Firestore for an Android Project but I'm having some trouble retrieving data when the phone is on Airplane mode. Here's my code:

```
public void loadThings() {
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    db.collection("medidas").whereEqualTo("id_user", mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                QuerySnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
                int tam = snapshot.getDocuments().size();
                data = new String[tam];
                StringBuilder temp;
                DocumentSnapshot doc;
                for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
                    temp = new StringBuilder();
                    doc = snapshot.getDocuments().get(i);

                    temp.append("Date: ").append(doc.get("fecha")).append(";");
                    temp.append("Min: ").append(doc.get("min")).append(";");
                    temp.append("Max: ").append(doc.get("max")).append(";");
                    temp.append("Avg: ").append(doc.get("avg")).append(";");


                    data[i] = temp.toString();
                }
                if(tam==0)
                {
                    noMeasures();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                data=null;
            }
            mLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mMeasuresAdapter.setMeasuresData(data);
            if (null == data) {
                showErrorMessage();
            } else {
                showMeasuresDataView();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The specific problem is that sometimes it takes to long to show the data (more than 10 seconds) while some others it shows the data inmediatly. Since the phone is on airplane mode is obvious that the data I'm retrieving comes from the cache. However, I don't understand why it is taking so long sometimes. Is there some way to tell firestore explicitly to bring data from the cache instead of trying to fetch it from the server? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

> Is there some way to tell firestore explicitly to bring data from the cache instead of trying to fetch it from the server?

Yes it is, starting with the `16.0.0` SDK version update, you can achieve this with the help of the [DocumentReference.get(Source source)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#get(com.google.firebase.firestore.Source)) and [Query.get(Source source)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#get(com.google.firebase.firestore.Source)) methods.

> By default, `get()` attempts to provide up-to-date data when possible by waiting for data from the server, but it may return cached data or fail if you are offline and the server cannot be reached. This behavior can be altered via the Source parameter.

So you can pass as an argument to the `DocumentReference` or to the `Query` the source, so we can force the retrieval of data from the `server only`, `chache only` or attempt server and fall back to the cache.

So in code might look like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference docIdRef = db.collection("yourCollection").document("yourDocument");
docIdRef.get(Source.CACHE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        //Get data from the documentSnapshot object
    }
});
```

In this case, we force the data to be retrieved from the `CACHE` only. If you want to force the data to be retrieved from the `SERVER` only, you should pass as an argument to the `get()` method, `Source.SERVER`. More informations [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Source).